# send post variables via jquery(ajax) to php himself document

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send post variables to php himself document via jQuery ajax, but after send, the post vars are not set.

the code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){

     do something
    }
<form id="form_login_pv">

Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">

<div class="send_login_button_pv">Login</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.send_login_button_pv').click(function(e){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data:$('#form_login_pv').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
                alert("mensaje enviado");

        }

});
});     

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you're submitting the form, so why use ajax ?

Comment: how can i do it  without ajax?

Comment: The usual way, by submitting the form with the proper action and method settings.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try to use form submit jquery function.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
    //do something
}

<form id="form_login_pv" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

Password: <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
<button type="submit" class="send_login_button_pv">Login</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('.send_login_button_pv').click(function(e)
  {
      e.preventDefault(); // just to make sure it wont perform other action 
      $("#form_login_pv").submit(function(){
          //afte server response code goes here
      });
  });     

</script>
```

Make sure form must have action set.

Comment: Because u were not actually submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data:$('#form_login_pv').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
        alert("mensaje enviado");
    }

});
```

Try this in jQuery ready event:

```
//you can also use an <input type="submit" value="login" /> instead ofusing a button!
$("#button_id").on("click",function(e){
    $("#form_login_pv").submit();
    return e.preventDefault();
});    

$("#form_login_pv").submit(function(e) {
    var email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var pass = $('input[name=pass]').val();

    // validate given values here
    // if bad value detected, output error and return false;

    if(!email.test(YOUR REGEX HERE)) {
        $('#error-message').text('Wrong E-Mail Format!');
        return false;
    }
    if(pass.length<6) {
        $('#error-message').text('Password to short! At least 6 Characters!');
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
            email: email,
            pass: pass,
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert("mensaje enviado");
        }
    });
    return e.preventDefault();
});
```

And don't forget to pervent the form from submitting via HTTP Post!

You can do this by returning false at the end of your button click event.

Or by using a method of your event object e, e.preventDefault();

I suggest to return e.preventDefault(); at the end of your click function!

You also can check if given variables are empty or validate them with javascript, before submitting via ajax!